# jQuery Answer to Dojo Widget infrastructure

Tags: javascript, jquery, dojo

I have worked a lot with Dojo in the past and really liked the widget infrastructure that it provides. You can easily separate code and html content, its nicely linked with the require-system used by dojo and last but not least you are given a builder that compresses all and everything into a single small file.

For a new project I would like to use jQuery and I am curious what widget/template/builder infrastructure you could use. I found some libraries here and there but I did not really get an impression of how a whole "stack" could look like.

I am looking forward to your suggestions!

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you need to do your project in JQuery rather than dojo ? You can easily use JQuery modules from dojo now with the AMD loaders...

Comment: Do you have any other requirements?

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked [jQueryUI](http://jqueryui.com/)?

Comment: Yes, I cannot find a convenient way to write HTML templates. Everything is in the JS files.

Comment: What do you mean by HTML templates? You want to use jQuery to build a web page? With jQueryUI you only have to provide proper class to DOM node, eg. `<body class="ui-dialog-content ui-widget-content">`

Comment: jQueryUI is a simple widget collection, I wouldn't recommend it if you need a solid MVC framework.

Answer (score 1):

Try [JavaScriptMVC](http://javascriptmvc.com/).

The essential component of this package is jQueryMX that provides a basic class framework with models, views (that use templates) and controllers.

Another part of the framework, StealJS, gives you dependency management and build tools that you need.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend Backbone http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/, it a good MVC framework too.

Answer (score 0):

Widget factory is your answer.
http://wiki.jqueryui.com/w/page/12138135/Widget-factory

WIth jQuery1.7 supporting Asynchronous Module Definition (AMD), HTML template can be easily supported by "text" and  isRender
http://www.roughlybrilliant.com/jsrender_json_apis_and_jquery_mobile

Pseudo Code:

```
define(["jquery", "text!templates/myTemplate.html"], function ($, myTemplate) {
    $.widget( "namespace.myWidget", $.mobile.listview, {
    ...
    });
});
```